# how to make a server and client run on any machine

Tags: c++, tcp, udp, client-server, broadcast

i created a client server program in c++. but my problem is that the client can only connect to the server if the server is on a certain computer because the client must know the server's ip address to connect by using this code:

```
ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.13.32.112");
```

so my question is how can i get the client to automatically find the server without me having to change the ip address in the code every time?

Comment: Is using a host name not possible?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what that is. can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From my comment:*

Why not use a host name?

A host name is a human friendly name that refers to one or more computers. An example of this is domain names on the internet - I don't need to type stack overflow's IP address(es), I just type stackoverflow.com.

In your situation you could set up a domain name to point at the server that you're trying to connect to, then resolve that host name to an IP address in your C++ code.

Comment: so when the client runs I would still have to tell it the server's host name or does it connect by itself?

Comment: You have to have some way of specifying the client, whether it's host name or IP address.

Comment: ok so its basically impossible for me to take the server and run it on another computer and the client has to find it?

Comment: Yes, unless you give the server a host name, then change the IP address that it's associated with it (via DNS). Even then there's a lag time where the new IP address filters through to the clients.

Comment: so what does INADDR_BRAODCAST do? i was told this might help but i'm guessing this information was wrong

Comment: That's used for allowing a server to bind to ports on all of its IP addresses. E.g. a server could run on 127.0.0.1, a 192.168.x.x address, and one or more external IP addresses. But you can also allow it to run on all of those. It doesn't allow you to swap between servers.